# Proof of Mackey's restriction formula for the restriction of an induced rerpesentation

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group with subgroup $H$ and suppose that $(\rho,W)$ is a representation of $G$. Then I want to prove that $$
\text{Res}_H^G(\text{Ind}_H^G(W))\cong\bigoplus_{s\in S}\text{Ind}_{H^s}^H(W^s),
$$
where $S$ is the set of representatives in $H\backslash G/H$ and $H^s=sHs^{-1}\cap H$ and $(\rho^s,W^s)$ is the representation of $H^s$ defined by $\rho^s(h)=\rho(s^{-1}hs)$. Now, I know this is proven in Linear Representations of Finite Groups by Serre, but I to be honest, I don't fully understand his proof. It seems that Serre uses a different definition of the induced representation, I defined it on the vector space of functions $$\text{Ind}_H^G(W)=\{f:G\to W\colon f(hg)=\rho(h)f(g)\}$$
and then together with a $G$-action on $\text{Ind}_H^G(W)$ by $(g\cdot f)(g')=f(g'g)$. Does anyone know a reference in which this decomposition is proven?

Comment: Your definition of induced representation is now more often called co-induction than induction; it turns out that the two are isomorphic when $G$ is a finite group (or more generally when $H$ has finite index in $G$)

Comment: First, the two $H$s should be distinct. You really don't want any opportunities for confusion in an already fairly confusing situation like this.

Comment: And as @Max said, your definition of "induction" is not really standard. It is easiest to find a proof of Mackey's Ind-Res formula using a different definition and a proof that the two definitions are equivalent.

Comment: I managed to prove my assertion fairly easy in the case that $H$ is a normal subgroup, which is sufficient for my purposes. Nevertheless, thank you all for thinking about this.