# Confused on definition of induced representations

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

*TL-DR:* I'm getting confused over the definition of induced representations. I don't have much of an intuition for them which is making it difficult to work with them. Can someone help me gain an intuition on these induced representations?

---

Let's set up a little bit of notation before we give the definition:

- Suppose that $X$ is a finite set and $W$ is a $k$-vector space. We may define $\mathcal{F}(X, W) = \{f : X → W\}$.
- Suppose that $H \leq G$ are groups. Then Now $\mathcal{F}(G,W)$ is a representation of $G \times H$ via $((g,h) \circ f)(x) = h f(g^{-1} x h) \quad \text{for $(g,h) \in G \times H$, $f \in \mathcal{F}(G,W)$ and $x \in G$}.$
- $\mathcal{F}(G, W)^H = \{ f \in \mathcal{F}(G, W) : f(x h) = h^{-1} f(x) \forall h \in H, x \in G \}$

Now we have this defined, here is the definition of induced representations I have been given:

- Suppose $H$ is a subgroup of a finite group $G$ and $W$ is a representation of $H$, then the induced representation $\mathrm{Ind}_G^H(W) = \mathcal{F}(G, W)^H$ is a representation of $G$.

Now I can work with all these symbols to an extent, but my abilities to understand or prove statements in representation theory where I see $\mathrm{Ind}$ written somewhere is limited because I don't have much intuition here. (e.g. Mackey's restriction formula (see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3417601/proof-of-mackeys-restriction-formula-for-the-restriction-of-an-induced-rerpesen#:%7E:text=Proof%20of%20Mackey%27s%20restriction%20formula%20for%20the%20restriction%20of%20an%20induced%20rerpesentation,-Ask%20Question&text=and%20then%20together%20with%20a,f(g%E2%80%B2g).) question for such a statement & proof.)

Can someone help me gain an intuition on these induced representations?

Comment: Do you know the concept of adjoint functors?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Not really, I'm afraid. I've not done any category theory - at my university representation theory is taught first in what I think is supposed to be a much more concrete (or at least category-theoryless) way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given our $H$-representation $W$, we want to extend it naturally to a $G$-representation. We can do this by taking the direct sum of copies of $W$ indexed by the left cosets of $H$ in $G$, which we can write as $g_iW$ for a set of coset representatives $g_i$. We can write the elements of $g_iW$ as $g_iw$ for $w\in W$. This is just book-keeping notation.

For $g\in G$, $w\in W$, and so $g_iw\in g_iW$, we may then define $g\cdot g_iw:=g_j(hw)$, where $gg_i=g_jh$ with $h\in H$. This really does define a $G$-representation on $\bigoplus_ig_iW$, and is a natural extension of the $H$-representation $W$.

Of course, there are alternative descriptions of this construction, but they all amount to the same thing.